# What is the time complexity of creating a heap using priority_queue and vector in C++ STL?

Tags: c++, stl, heap

We have been taught that time complexity for building a min or max heap from scratch takes `O(n)` time.

But since priority_queue in STL takes `O(log n)` time for insertion,

So making heap from scratch using **priority_queue** would take `O(n*log n)` time. isn't it?
and same goes for using vector also.
Is there any other way in which I could use any built-in function from STL to create heap in `O(n)` time?

Answer (score 0):

`std::priority_queue`'s constructors [all have O(N) complexity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue)<sup>1</sup>, where N is the number of elements you pass.

E.g.

> `explicit priority_queue( const Compare& compare = Compare(), const Container& cont = Container() );` (3)
>
> 3. Copy-constructs the underlying container `c` with the contents of
>    `cont`. Copy-constructs the comparison functor `comp` with the contents of
>    `compare`. Calls `std::make_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp)`.

> **Complexity**
>
> 3. O(N) comparisons, where N is `cont.size()`.  Additionally, O(N)
>    calls to the constructor of `value_type`, where N is `cont.size()`.

1. Besides the move constructor, which steals it's argument in constant time.